# Problem with LISP gensym and Let Functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm working on a project for a program that takes regular expressions, turns them into the corresponding NFA and then allows you to test if certain input strings are accepted or not by the NFA.

I'm using the function `gensym` to generate the numbers that correspond to the states of the NFA, only i like to take only the numeric part of it by using `*gensym-counter*`, everything was working fine but all the sudden i encountered this weird problem:

The function i use to call `gensym` is this

```
(defun gensympp ()
  (let ((x (gensym)))
    *gensym-counter*))
```

so it returns only the increased number after calling gensym on `x` so i can use it for the NFA states, today i was running some final tests and suddenly the function doesn't increase the `*gensym-counter*` anymore so every state is just the starting number (set with a let at the start of the function), the only way to fix this seems to put a `(defparameter x 1)` (the number doesn't matter) at the start of the code, with that the gensym updates normally and everything works fine like before, i really have no idea what could've caused this as i only made small formatting adjustments to the code that was working perfectly a week ago, i'm new to lisp as well so there might just be something obvious i'm ignoring, if needed i can post the rest of the code where i use the gensym but even just calling the function `(gensympp)` by itself from the listener doesn't increase the number

Thanks a lot in advance for the help

Comment: Why use `gensym` if you're not using the symbol? Just use your own global integer variable that you increment.

Comment: @Barmar yeah my first version just used a global integer but our professor doesn't want us to use global variables so we must use gensym, i should've mentioned that

Comment: You could use a lexical variable around the function: `(let ((counter 0)) (defun gensympp () (incf counter) counter))`

Comment: But I can't think of a reason why `*gensym-counter*` isn't being incremented. It should be incremented as long as you call `gensym` with no argument.

Comment: I wonder if the compiler is optimizing out the call to `gensym` because you never use the value, ignoring the fact that it has a side effect.

Comment: Try disassembling the function to see if it calls `gensym`.

Comment: @Barmar when i disassemble gensympp i don't see any call to gensym, i've been on this all day, only thing that makes it work is adding the (defparameter x 1) at the start for some reason, which is weird because it used to work perfectly

Comment: Try returning `(values *gensym-counter* x)`

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a warning about "variable bound but not used".

Comment: @Barmar i am getting the warning i just didn't think much of it, i tried just now to used the x variable so to get rid of it but the function still doesn't increase the number

Comment: @Barmar returning (values *gensym-counter* x) fixed it! thank you so much, if i do have time i'll also try to implement the version with a lexical variable around the function like you suggested

Comment: You are not allowed to use global variables? But `*gensym-counter*` is a global variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is optimizing out the call to `gensym` because you never use `x`. You can trick it into thinking that the variable is used by returning it as a second value.

```
(defun gensympp ()
  (let ((x (gensym)))
    (values *gensym-counter* x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that what your professor wants is to enumerate the states freshly for each NFA instance, starting from 0 or 1. So that is to say, the state counter is not a global variable, but an instance variable in some NFA construction context object.

(If you think about it, this consistent numbering will make your NFA machines easier to read by humans, in whatever form you dump them. If you construct the same NFA twice, the two will agree in the graph shape *and* the numbering of the states. All the textbook examples of this stuff I have ever seen number the states from 0 or 1 in each successive diagram.)

Note also that you can give a custom prefix to `gensym`, which could be an empty string:

```
[1]> (gensym "")
#:3318
```

Unless you actually need the states to be integers for the sake of some numeric calculations, they could just be symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are not meant to use global variables: using a global variable that happens to be provided by the system is, in fact, using global variables.

What you should do instead is have some state object which you pass around which keeps track of the current count, and lets get the next count on demand.

This could be as simple as an integer, but in fact you may want something mutable.  There are lots of ways of doing this.  One easy one is

```
(defun make-counter (&key (initial-value 0)
                          (increment 1))
  (let ((current (- initial-value increment)))
    (lambda ()
      (incf current increment))))

(defun next-count (counter)
  (funcall counter))
```

Now:

```
> (loop with counter = (make-counter :increment 3)
             repeat 4
             collect (next-count counter))
(0 3 6 9)
```

But there are many others.

In the question you say that you are binding `*gensym-counter*` yourself.  Well, if that's what you're doing then just use your own special variable: it doesn't even need to be globally special:

```
(defmacro with-counter ((&key (initial-value 0)) &body forms)
  `(let ((%the-count% (1- ,initial-value)))
     (declare (special %the-count%))
     ,@forms))

(defun next-count ()
  (declare (special %the-count%))
  (unless (boundp '%the-count%)
    (error "not in dynamic extent of WITH-COUNTER"))
  (incf %the-count%))
```